# Spring HttpSession with Redis not saving SESSION cookie value

Tags: spring, cookies, redis, netflix-zuul, httpsession

We are building a system based on microservices with Spring Cloud where we use Zuul as the edge server and some backend microservices. In one of these backend services we use Redis to manage `HttpSession` and store some user related objects.

Everything goes fine when accessing directly the microservice, but things go wrong when acessing through Zuul, because the backing microservice always gets a new `HttpSession` ID. I tried passing the cookie with `JSESSIONID` and `SESSION` forward to the microservice using a `ZuulFilter` but the microservice ends up not using the cookie values to create the spring:sessions in Redis.

Can anyone help in determining how to make Spring Session use the Cookie value, instead of the `HttpSession.ID`?

We are using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you find any answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar. You might have a look here: https://github.com/khauser/microservices4vaadin

There needs to be a change to DefaultCookieSerializer:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
  CookieHttpSessionStrategy cookieHttpSessionStrategy = new CookieHttpSessionStrategy();
  DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
  cookieSerializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
  cookieSerializer.setCookiePath("/");
  cookieSerializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$");
  cookieHttpSessionStrategy.setCookieSerializer(cookieSerializer);
  return cookieHttpSessionStrategy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this in application.properties and it will fix your problem

```
zuul.sensitive-headers=
```